# named query in NHibernate with not equal operator

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, spring.net, named-query

NHibernate throw exception with sql server not equal to operator `<>`.

```
<sql-query name="Select">
    <return alias="OrderStock" class="OrderStock"/>
select * from OrderStock WHERE dh.DATE_UNLOADED <> '1753-01-01'
</sql-query>
```

> Name cannot begin with the '>' character

Comment: Did you try wrapping your query in `<![CDATA[]]>`?

Comment: no i did not tried that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can escape symbols `<>` with `&lt;&gt;` like this:

```
<sql-query name="Select">
    <return alias="OrderStock" class="OrderStock"/>
select * from OrderStock WHERE dh.DATE_UNLOADED &lt;&gt; '1753-01-01'
</sql-query>
```

Or we can use xml raw text escaping with `<![CDATA[ .... ]]>`:

```
<sql-query name="Select">
    <return alias="OrderStock" class="OrderStock"/>
<![CDATA[
select * from OrderStock WHERE dh.DATE_UNLOADED <> '1753-01-01'
]]>
</sql-query>
```